# Selecting an Excel Shape or finding its topLeftCell

Tags: office-js

In office-js, the Shape object does not have a Select or Activate method. In order to mimic this action, I wanted to use something similar to the VBA TopLeftCell property, which also doesn't exist.
So I thought, let me just write a function that gets that range:

```
async function GetTopLeftOfShape(sht: Excel.Worksheet, shp: Excel.Shape) {
  shp.load("top, left");
  sht.getUsedRangeOrNullObject();
  await shp.context.sync();
  const shpTop = shp.top;
  const shpLeft = shp.left;
  let topLeftCell = sht.getRange("A1");
  let cellTop: number = 0;
  let cellLeft: number = 0;
  do {
    topLeftCell = topLeftCell.getOffsetRange(0, 1);
    topLeftCell.load("left");
    await sht.context.sync();
    cellLeft = topLeftCell.left.valueOf();
  } while (cellLeft < shpLeft);
  do {
    topLeftCell = topLeftCell.getOffsetRange(1, 0);
    topLeftCell.load("top");
    await sht.context.sync();
    cellTop = topLeftCell.top.valueOf();
  } while (cellTop < shpTop);

  topLeftCell = topLeftCell.getOffsetRange(-1, -1);
  await sht.context.sync();
  return topLeftCell;
}
```

###Update 2023-1-17 ###
The code does not work in my office-js project, but it works just fine in Scriptlab. What is going on?

###Update 2023-1-18###

I call the function above like so (shp and sht are defined and set to the shape in question and it's parent worksheet elsewhere in this code):

```
  let shpTopLeftCell = await GetTopLeftOfShape(sht, shp);
  shpTopLeftCell.select();
  await sht.context.sync();
```

But nothing happens; the cell selection does not change, nor do I get any errors.

Comment: You need to say much more than "does not work". What do you expect to see and what do you actually see.

Comment: Thanks @RickKirkham. I expect to receive a cell reference to the top-left cell of the shape. Instead, I seem to get nothing returned.

Comment: I've edited the question to add the lines of code that call the function

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I cracked it myself. This code works (though I have changed the function to return just the address of the cell):

```
async function GetTopLeftOfShape(sht: Excel.Worksheet, shp: Excel.Shape) {
  shp.load("top, left");
  await shp.context.sync();
  const shpTop: number = shp.top.valueOf();
  const shpLeft: number = shp.left.valueOf();
  let topLeftCell = sht.getRange("A1");
  let cellTop: number = 0;
  let cellLeft: number = 0;
  let rowCt: number = 1;
  let colCt: number = 1;
  do {
    topLeftCell = sht.getRange("A1").getOffsetRange(rowCt, colCt);
    topLeftCell.load("left,top");
    await sht.context.sync();
    cellLeft = topLeftCell.left.valueOf();
    cellTop = topLeftCell.top.valueOf();
    if (cellLeft < shpLeft) {
      colCt++;
    }
    if (cellTop < shpTop) {
      rowCt++;
    }
  } while (cellLeft < shpLeft || cellTop < shpTop);

  topLeftCell = sht.getRange("A1").getOffsetRange(rowCt - 1, colCt - 1);
  topLeftCell.load("address");
  await topLeftCell.context.sync();
  return topLeftCell.address.valueOf();
}
```